# obtaining a distribution from a multiplication using montecarlo

Tags: r, distribution, montecarlo

From a=b*c
I need to find mean, P10, P50 and P90 of "a", sapling from distributions of "b" and "c", I tried to use Montecarlo for that, but what I get is an error.
I know it is a bit silly, but can you help me with that
Please find the R code I used below

```
library(MonteCarlo)
mult<-function(a,b) {sample<-rnorm(b,c)
a<-sample*sample
mean<-mean(a)
return(list("mean"=mean))}
b_grid<-c(50,100,250,500)
c_grid<-seq(1,2,0.2)

param_list=list("b"=b_grid, "c"=c_grid)

MC_result<-MonteCarlo(func=mult, nrep=1000, param_list=param_list)
```

Comment: What are distributions for 'b' and 'c'? Because `rnorm(b,c)` doesn't make sense

Comment: Are `b` and `c` independent random variables?

Comment: What are distributions for 'b' and 'c'? Because rnorm(b,c) doesn't make sense (Agree) I was following the example presented in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MonteCarlo/versions/1.0.5

Comment: Are b and c independent random variables? Yes band c are independent random variables